# Non-canonical mode don't work on backtick

Tags: c

When I launch my program using backticks like:

```
cat `./my_program`
```

I expect my read() to read character by character, it still reads line by line. The non-canonical mode of my terminal doesn't work. I don't really understand why.

Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main()
{
    struct termios  term_setting;
    char            *term;
    char            buff[10];

    term = getenv("TERM");
    tgetent(NULL, term);
    tcgetattr(STDOUT_FILENO, &term_setting);    //
    term_setting.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);   //set my term in echo and non-canonique mode
    tcsetattr(STDOUT_FILENO, 0, &term_setting); //
    for (;;){
        bzero(buff, sizeof(char) * 10);
        read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, 9);
        printf("%s\n", buff);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? *How* doesn't it work? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Because stdout isn’t the terminal anymore. Did you mean to get/set those attributes on `STDIN_FILENO`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude By don't work i mean the read() read line per line and not caracter by caractere

Comment: `bzero` is obsolete, use `memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);`

Comment: @Douky: You've explained what you mean by "don't work", but that information should be in the question, not just in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ry-♦ say in comment:
`Because stdout isn’t the terminal anymore. Did you mean to get/set those attributes on STDIN_FILENO?`
It's exactly my probleme, thx!

Comment: Better to use `/dev/tty` and only fall back to stdin if you can't. Or at least check `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` before you start doing *terminal* control.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion here: what do you expect

```
cat `./my_program`
```

to produce?

`my_program` copies standard input to standard output, in an infinite loop, even after reaching the end of file, which you do not test, producing unexpected output.

The shell collects this output either in a file, in a pseudo-terminal or possibly via a pipe and, once completed, passes it to `cat` as command line arguments, but since you must kill `my_program` in order to complete its output, the shell will abort this operation too.

`cat` expects options and filenames as command line arguments, probably not what you type.

Regarding the change of settings for the terminal, you could use `STDIN_FILENO` or just `0` instead of `STDOUT_FILENO`, since you want to change the behavior of the input handle.

Comment: ~~~
cat `./my_program`
~~~
cat is an example. The probleme is, i expect my program to print each caractere i type whitout waiting a new line (The non-canonique mode for read), then send the output to cat.
But in my case, when i start my program in backtick, he wait i press enter for execute the next instruction.

@Ry-♦ actualy find my probleme in comment

Comment: Use `STDIN_FILENO` to change terminal settings